# dojo Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dojo

I can use `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` to show the Dropdown box. But It requests all data from the store `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` at once that I Don't want. I want it to query the store with the current value of the textbox and show the Autocompleter options.

Answer (score 1):

A more complete example as above but equals of valid. But in my case I use [QueryReadStore](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/data/QueryReadStore)

```
 this.store = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({
                url: 'url',
                sortFields :  [{attribute: 'attribute', descending: true}],
                requestMethod : "get"}
            );

callSuggest : function(){
        var fetch = {
                query: {attribute: "*"},
                queryOptions: {
                    ignoreCase: true,
                    deep: true
                },
                serverQuery: this.searchParam,
                onComplete: dojo.hitch(this, function(result, dataObject){
                    //do something
                }),
                onError: function(errText){
                    console.error('error');
                }
            };
        this.store.fetch(fetch);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to perform something like this I assume,

> itemStore .fetch({   query: { name: "*pepper*", aisle: "Spices" },
>   queryOptions: { ignoreCase: true },   onComplete:   ... });

Please see this link for a complete listing and details. 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/filteringitems.html

Comment: No That still requires the While data to be downloaded from the store. Its just a custom query on the store. to receive partial data from the store.